# use IPOPT error with , Builtins fzn_all_different_int not implemented or not recognized

Tags: minizinc, ipopt

thanks a lot .
use IPOPT as backend of Minizinc , and following the help file with the setting of :

{
"id" : "org.coin-or.ipopt",
"name" : "Ipopt",
"executable" : "\IPOPT\coin.mswin64.20230221\ipopt.exe",
"version": "3.5.6",
"supportsFzn":true,
"supportsNL":false
}

but the error coming :

*Something should not have happen in file 'C:\gitlab-runner\builds\dk_a-R2B\0\minizinc\minizinc\solvers\nl\nl_file.cpp' line 393. Message:
Builtins fzn_all_different_int not implemented or not recognized.
Note: the NL component is still in development!*

**is that mean all golbal constraint is not support in NL ?**

for reference the binary file down load from
https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source-solvers/